# Google maps: nearbysearch parameters

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get cities near by current city using this method. I put type locality but it does not return many results. Is there another method to get the nearest cities from a place and to also specify the radius?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?type=locality&key=AIzaSyCkvow9LlFNOywy8lzaekn-xROBZRsSFvU&radius=30000&location=51.509865,%20-0.118092
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
sb.append("location=" + your_latitude + "," + your_longitude);
sb.append("&radius=3500");   //specify radius
sb.append("&types=" + "atm");   //specify type of place
sb.append("&sensor=true");
sb.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
// Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data
PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

// Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
```

for Url:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.873751,90.396454&radius=500&types=atm&key=YOUR_API_KEY

For different type of place see:

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: yes but for locality it does not return results ,  for other types yes

Comment: locality is not added in supported type by google...you can try with `city`.. above url shows u different supported place type